# In-App Purchase Auto-renewable Subscriptions

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an app that sells Virtual Phone Numbers. When an user subscribes, we deliver a new virtual number and the user can manage this number within the app. After that, the user can receive calls but not necesarily through the app. I mean, after the initial purchase the user does not need to open the app to use the service but I need a way to check the subscription status monthly. My question is, can I set up a cron in the server to check the next receipts even the user wont open the app anymore?
Is it possible to sell a subscription service that is not delivered through the app? Thanks.

Comment: Just an advice : first of all, I would strongly recommend you to be sure that your service is eligible to the auto renewable subscriptions. It's not clear from Apple doc, but they "tend" to reject apps that are not *magazines* and use auto renew subscriptions. I had this experience personally and had to switch to "classic" (=non auto renenable) subscription for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this service that manages IAP and push notifications..
http://urbanairship.com/

IF your service is eligible for auto-renewable subscriptions you can use that ( this is tricky because they reject this if the app dosen't give content. see more here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html )

Comment: I didn't test it yet. I will be working on this the next couple of days. It seems to be possible. I will be back with my comments after I finish the job. Also I will be back when apple accept/reject the app. Thanks!

Comment: You really need to give content to the user for apple to accept your app with auto-renew subscription. I guess you already read that. I was rejected because of auto renew subscriptions for an app that offered a paid service. They didn't like that and suggested subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done this myself, but the gist I get from the store docs is that you will verify the receipt and get an updated transaction if the subscription has been renewed. So presumably on your server you have some indication of when the original subscription was purchased and the time, so you would check before it expires and get the new transition.

I'd suggest maybe using push notification if this were to fail, to engage the user to update/renew.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Auto-renewable subscription from apple to serve your users.

1. When user buy the subscription first time store the receipt in the server.
2. Maintain the expiry date of the subscription per user in the server DB.
3. Run the cron job and check for the "Active Status" of the subscription via apple APIs http://tinyurl.com/ay2labm
4. Depending on the status you can extend the service to your users.

   http://tinyurl.com/aeh9f84

Comment: could you give me these links in more detail! 1st link is redirecting to other apple developer url